# having 'Measure' > 0 syntax does not work in mdx query

Tags: sql-server, mdx

Hope you're doing well
I've written an MDX query as you can see below :

```
with member [Measures].[TOTAL] AS
SUM(Periodstodate([DimTime].[Year].[(All)] ,[DimTime].[Year].currentmember)
,[Measures].[IndentCount])

Select {[Measures].[IndentCount],[Measures].[TOTAL]}  
   having [Measures].[IndentCount] > 0 on 0 , 
   non empty [DimTime].[Year].[Year] on 1
from [Procurement]
```

The problem is despite using `having [Measures].[IndentCount] > 0` I still see the null value for my measure as you can see below :

[image] .
I want to know what the problem would be???
I have this problem even when I use Filter function

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You put the `HAVING` clause in the `ON COLUMNS` axis (or `ON 0`) which attempts to filter out any column which has a null or zero IndentCount. Instead you need to move it to the `ON ROWS` axis (or `ON 1`) if you want it eliminate some rows.

I would also suggest you may optimize the performance by using the `NonEmpty` function instead of `HAVING`. Since you can’t have a zero or negative IndentCount the following will do what you want and will perform better since it will only calculate the TOTAL measure for rows you will end up keeping.

```
with member [Measures].[TOTAL] AS
SUM(Periodstodate([DimTime].[Year].[(All)] ,[DimTime].[Year].currentmember)
,[Measures].[IndentCount])

Select {[Measures].[IndentCount],[Measures].[TOTAL]}  
   on 0 , 
   NonEmpty([DimTime].[Year].[Year], [Measures].[IndentCount]) on 1
from [Procurement]
```